GKE Workload Identity: Failed to generate federated token using STS: googleapi: got HTTP response code 400
I am observing weird behaviour in applications deployed in our GKE Cluster enabled with workload identity.
Environment: GKE 1.29 Cluster version
Codebase: Java v17
Issue:
Once in a while applications are unable to upload to GCS from applications deployed in GKE cluster with below errors
The weird thing is the issue gets resolved when I restart the application container. So, I believe I might be missing something regarding token refresh or initialising.
Error logged in application
Exception when uploading file, Source File = /tmp/451e85b6b7.pdf, Target Bucket = <bucket_name>, Target File Path = 2024-05/85b6b7.pdf, e = Unexpected Error code 400 trying to get security access token from Compute Engine metadata for the default service account: 400 Bad Request: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"ID Token issued at 1716609959 is stale to sign-in."}

Logs from gke-metadata-server:
metadata.go:205] [conn-id:5ec57c8b931fa2dd rpc-id:ec4376cd1abad5d6 remote-addr:XXXXXXXXX:53274 pod:services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d] "/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" HTTP/200, started at 2024-05-27 02:48:22.726856205 +0000 UTC m=+176189.906840050

federated_token.go:91] [conn-id:5ec57c8b931fa2dd rpc-id:0d7c9ea31be25280 background-id:2e1fa74e2fc26c7a remote-addr:xxxxxxxx:53274 pod:services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d] Fetching federated token for pod services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d

loading_cache.go:231] [conn-id:5ec57c8b931fa2dd rpc-id:0d7c9ea31be25280 background-id:2e1fa74e2fc26c7a remote-addr:xxxxxxx:53274 pod:services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d] Loading new entry succeeded

serviceaccounts.go:177] [conn-id:5ec57c8b931fa2dd rpc-id:0d7c9ea31be25280 remote-addr:xxxxxx:53274 pod:services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d] Failed to fetch token for pod services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d: generic::invalid_argument: loading: getFederatedToken("sa-generator@xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "", "", services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d): loading: while exchanging k8s token for federated token: failed to generate federated token using STS: googleapi: got HTTP response code 400 with body: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"ID Token issued at 1716609959 is stale to sign-in."}

metadata.go:214] [conn-id:5ec57c8b931fa2dd rpc-id:0d7c9ea31be25280 remote-addr:xxxxxxxx:53274 pod:services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d] "/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" HTTP/400: generic::invalid_argument: loading: getFederatedToken("sa-generator@xxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com", "", "", services/generator-deploy-helm-5965cc4488-sss7d): loading: while exchanging k8s token for federated token: failed to generate federated token using STS: googleapi: got HTTP response code 400 with body: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"ID Token issued at 1716609959 is stale to sign-in."}, Reason: "STS", UserMessage: "400 Bad Request: {\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"ID Token issued at 1716609959 is stale to sign-in.\"}", started at 2024-05-27 02:48:22.735619218 +0000 UTC m=+176189.915603048

Setup:
I have followed the google documentation to setup workload identity setup GKE-Workloadidentity
I expected the GKE workload identity to work seamlessly. However its not the case. I have also checked the google cloud's official troubleshooting guide, but was unable to solve the issue.
Observations:

GKE-metadata server is running fine without any restarts
Service Account is correctly bind with google service account as the issue gets resolved on the container restart.

K8s Service-account definition
Name:                generator-rbac-sa
Namespace:           services
Annotations:         iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: sa-generator@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Image pull secrets:  docker-credentials
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>


Already checked a below SO questions but unable to get solution yet:

1
2
3


Please create a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue.
